# Joda time - minus Duration from DateTime

Tags: java, jodatime

I've searched around but cannot find an answer for this.

I have a Duration:

```
Duration dur = Duration.ofMillis(50);
```

and I have a DateTime:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.now();
```

How do I subtract the Duration from the DateTime? I can see the method `DateTime.Minus(ReadableDuration)` so I thought I could do this:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.now().minus(dur);
```

But apparently Duration does not extend ReadableDuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Joda time 2.2 API](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/), the class `Duration` implements `ReadableDuration`. So, `Duration` is a subtype of `ReadableDuration`.

```
public final class Duration
       extends BaseDuration
       implements ReadableDuration, Serializable
```

See http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html.

Comment: Ah! I was importing java.time.Duration, not the JodaTime version.